# inserting rows to mysql table containing predefined Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was looking for the solution of this problem for some time and did not manage to find anything satisfactory. I know that similar problems were many times answered but there are usually workarounds rather than standard solutions for them.

The problem in my particular case is:

I have one table that contains predefined Primary Key that cannot be used as auto increment. It is predefined and it is also used by several other tables as a foreign key.

NID - my Primary Key

PID - the key from external source

Serial

bla1

bla2

NID is already in table ids (target table), not in source table

PID is already in source file/table, not in target table

other columns are in both tables

The pair NID-PID would be a unique match as these would be used further after matching.

Now I need to be able to insert values to this table on a weekly basis as these would be sent to me in csv/excel files, hundreds of records, so some easy way would be best, especially as easy way is easy to validate the import process.

Since there is no auto increment PK, I get an error:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'NID'

I was thinking about creating unique index on multiple fields like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_index ON ids (NID,PID);
```

But it did not work very well either:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '107521' for key 'unique_index'

I also tried to create separate table with data to be imported, but I get the same error.

The question is: what is the best way to insert records to table that contains PK and continue to do so on regular basis without altering existing data? What should I do to achieve this?

I would really appreciate any help since I'm stuck.

Comment: A primary key is unique by definition. Multiple rows cannot have the same primary key. Either drop the primary key or do not insert duplicate rows.

Comment: @kordirko Thank you for your comment. It can certainly be helpful to remove PK on NID, since NID is unique by design as there are no duplicates (and will not be) in this table. Each of the rows I am trying to insert from external file (at least at this stage) is unique.